# EMC Recoverpoint works for database?

Tags: postgresql, storage

As a solution for replication, to protect VM, LUNs and recovery including database, EMC Recoverpoint was presented by our vendor.
But in EMC paper's, the only one database related example ilustrates Vplex Metro with Oracle RAC.
My topology will use Postgresql.

Anyone have already recovered some database using EMC Recoverpoint?

Comment: I suggest you to read [Making a Base Backup Using the Low Level API](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP) section of the documentation. Most probably a scenario like 1- start base backup, 2- start emc backup, 3- stop base backup will solve.

Comment: Hi Sahap, I read the section that you indicated and this brought some ideas. Although the EMC Recoverpoint process is continuous (as I understand it) as soon as possible I will try to restore some period between _pg_start_backup_ and _pg_stop_backup_.
Thank you for your help!